# Compare HashMap and List and return value

Tags: android, list, hashmap

I've stored contacts in user's phone in a Map with phoneNumbers as keys and contactNames as values. Also, I've retrieved phone_number stored in Firebase when users signed up. In the method below, I'm comparing this map and the List.

public static Collection contains(Map map, List list) {

```
    Collection<String> keys = map.keySet();
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (String listItem:list) {
        if (keys.contains(listItem)){
            result.add(listItem);
        }
    }
    return result;  
}
```

When the Map's key match, phone_number retrieved from Firebase, I want to get value associated with it. How can I please do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a HashMap

```
   //Considering this stored contacts
    Map<String, String> contactsStored = new HashMap<>();
    contactsStored.put("999 999 999", "Anne");
    contactsStored.put("000 000 000", "Jonh");

    //and this firebase data               
    List<String> firebaseNumbers =  new ArrayList<>();
    firebaseNumbers.add("000 000 000");

    for (String firebaseNumberKey : firebaseNumbers) {
        contactsStored.get(firebaseNumberKey);
    }
```